# Beagle Bone Black I2C2 Issues

Tags: i2c, beagleboneblack

I am having troubles using an [I2C sensor](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-htu21d-f-temperature-humidity-sensor.pdf) with the Beagle Bone Black (BBB). The BBB is running a newly flashed 18.04 Ubuntu image specifically for the BBB.

I wired the sensor (VIN, GND, SCL, SDA) to the corresponding I2C2 pins (4, 2, 19, 20) on the BBB using the below pinout.

[image: BBB Pinout]
The sensor is supposed to be using address 0x40, but scanning I2C2 (using `i2cdetect -r 2`) does not show the sensor.

[image: i2cdetect -r 2 output]

I have tested this with two separate sensors as I thought at first I may have fried the original sensor somehow, but the results are the same. In fact, running the I2C2 scan command yields the exact same results when nothing is connected at all.

I have read in many places that I2C2 may not be enabled by default, but I assume it is enabled in my case as I can scan I2C2 without getting an error. Is this assumption incorrect? Again, this is a freshly flashed BBB, and I have not enabled/disabled anything - it should be in the default state.

I have also verified the connectivity of my wires between the sensor and BBB. The voltage between VIN and GND on the chip is 3.3V, so it is definitely being powered.

Why can't I connect to my I2C sensors using the BBB?

Answer (score 1):

it could be that the source you are using is outdated or not a viable entry for i2c.

Also, you could use this command to make sure i2c2 pins are available:

```
config-pin p9.21 i2c

config-pin p9.22 i2c
```

This may work, also. If this does not work, please reply with your entire source.

Seth

P.S. Also, if you have time, you may want to get an i2c library to use if your software falls short of setting up your own i2c library. They have smbus2 you can install with pip and other i2c libraries out there still.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by my 'source' (I'm relatively new at working with Linux at this level). Running `config-pin -q p9.21` and `config-pin -q p9.22` confirms that they are both set to i2c mode.

Comment: Hello...okay. Source or software if you prefer is what I was asking you to show.

Comment: It is running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and i2ctools is version 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you should check (in random order).

List all I2C buses wich `i2cdetect -l` and try them all. Depending on the platform, the i2c bus number in Linux may be different from the peripheral number used in the datasheet and pinout. E.g. "I2C2" might be bus i2c-1 or i2c-3 in Linux).

Use an oscilloscope or logical analyzer to see if the SCL and SDA lines are being driven. If they aren't check the bus number as above. If they are, then check whether the device gives an ACK; if it doesn't, anything else will never work: double-check the chip slave address. There are cheap logical analyzers that you can buy and user with [pulseview](https://sigrok.org/wiki/PulseView).

Simply load the Linux driver for your chip (see [the kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/instantiating-devices.html#method-4-instantiate-from-user-space) on how to do it from userspace for a quick test). Then see check if the device appears or use `dmesg` to see any kernel error messages while probing.

Comment: `i2cdetect -l` shows 3 I2C buses, but `i2cdetect -y -r` for all three shows nothing at 0x40. Have not had a chance to try your other suggestions yet.